# Unable to access django API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have the following settings.py.I only have token authentication

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
```

views.py

```
class UserView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print(request.user)
```

When I try to access a particular url,I am getting the following error

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Token

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

I have tried removing IsAuthenticated,then it works but the user is anonymoususer.How do I fix this? I want to access the current logged in user details. Also,how do I access it at url level .For example,I have a url "localhost:8000/api/values/param1/param2" How can I give a token here? I am getting the error when I try to access with this url actually

Answer (score 1):

Congrats, your API endpoints are now secured! this is the normal behaviour. You need to provide a token when trying to access ressources. This is from the front-end perspective.

Do check out the documentation:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal "Token", with whitespace separating the two strings. For example:

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Comment: where do I give the token? I mean which file? views.py or settings.py

Comment: I mean do I need to give  the token at url because I want to access the logged in user token

Comment: To quickly test your authentication system (eg. generate a token, register a new user, authenticate a user), you can use Postman.

Comment: yes but how do I access it at url level .For example,I have a url "http://localhost:8000/api/values/param1/param2" How can I give a token here? I am getting the error when I try to access with this url actually @Ivan